# SQL:Pivot table which includes sum and percentage total

Tags: sql, pivot

I'm trying to recreate a view in Tableau as a view in SQL. It requires me pivoting a table based on month and not only summing the amount but I also need to sum by margin and also create a Margin % row.The desired output is

```
BUSINESS_UNIT   CLASS          JANUARY  FEBRUARY    MARCH
202            Cost of Sales    100    (null)       60
202            Revenue          200    80           (null)
202            Margin           x      xx           xxx
202            Margin %         x%     xx%          xxx%
```

I can pivot based on Month but how do perform twos sums in one pivot table and how would I go about including a percenatge row also?

Code so far

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT
            [Business_Unit]
            ,[Class]
            ,Month as Period
            ,[Amount]
            --,Margin                               
      FROM [sample_table]
      where [Class] in ('Revenue','Cost of Sales') )AS T
    PIVOT(SUM(Amount)
            FOR Period IN ([January],[February],[March])) as Pvt
```

I have included my code so far http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06bafc/6

Comment: I don't understand margin %.  Is it a percent of total for all 3 months?  So January would be (300/440) or 68.1% Feb would be 18.18 March 13.63?

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest SQL I've done. but this seems to work...

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/06bafc/60/0

What it does is build on what you've done by generating a margin line and adding a total column
Using this line and total we can then calculate the % of margin.  Grouping SETS allowed me to generate the multiple rows, subtotals and totals, Since I knew the only additional line generated would have a null class, I was able to set the Name of the class to margin when null.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
      Business_Unit
      ,case when class is NULL then 'Margin' else class end as Class
      ,Sum(January) as January
      ,Sum(February) as February 
      ,Sum(March) as march
      ,Sum(coalesce(January,0)+coalesce(February,0)+coalesce(March,0)) as Total
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        *
      FROM
        (SELECT
                [Business_Unit]
                ,[Class]
                ,Month as Period
                ,[Amount]
                --,Margin                               
          FROM [sample_table]
          where [Class] in ('Revenue','Cost of Sales') )AS T
        PIVOT(SUM(Amount)
                FOR Period IN ([January],[February],[March])) as Pvt
      ) as Base
    GROUP BY Grouping sets 
    ((Business_Unit,Class,January,February,March,
      coalesce(January,0)+coalesce(February,0)+coalesce(March,0))
     ,(Business_Unit)
     ))
    SELECT * 
    FROM  CTE UNION
    SELECT Business_Unit
      ,'Margin %'
      ,January*100.00/Total
      ,February*100.00/Total
      ,March*100.00/Total
      ,Total*100.00/Total
    FROM CTE
    WHERE CLASS='Margin'
```